# Is there a direct service-now rest api to run user criteria diagnostic for KB documents?

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

Is there a direct service-now rest api to check whether the user(based on user sys-id) have read access to a KB article?
Or is it possible to  get contextual API search list based on user's sysid (based on user-criteria)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the user credentials to access the respective kb_knowledge query, you should have webservice access role enabled for the user to do this.